# grouping by id and a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df

```
df=DataFrame({'id':    ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b'],
'min':[10,17,21,22,22,7,58,15,17,19,19,19,19,19,25,26,26],
'day':[15,15,15,15,15,17,17,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,57,57,57]})
```

that looks like

```
   id  min  day
0   a   10   15
1   a   17   15
2   a   21   15
3   a   30   15
4   a   50   15
5   a   57   17
6   a   58   17
7   b   15   41
8   b   17   41
9   b   19   41
10  b   19   41
11  b   19   41
12  b   19   41
13  b   19   41
14  b   25   57
15  b   26   57
16  b   26   57
```

I want a new column that categorizes the data in a certain format based on the id and the relationship between the rows as follows, if min value difference for consecutive rows is less than 8 and the day value is the same I want to assign them to the same group, so my output would look like.

```
   id  min  day  category
0   a   10   15     1
1   a   17   15     1
2   a   21   15     1
3   a   30   15     2
4   a   50   15     3
5   a   57   17     4
6   a   58   17     4
7   b   15   41     5
8   b   17   41     5
9   b   19   41     5
10  b   19   41     5
11  b   19   41     5
12  b   19   41     5
13  b   19   41     5
14  b   25   57     6
15  b   26   57     6
16  b   26   57     6
```

Comment: Your `df = ` line doesn't match your first shown dataframe which doesn't match your second dataframe..

Comment: Yes, I see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps. let me know your views.

All the best.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'id':    ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b'],
                'min':[10,17,21,22,22,7,58,15,17,19,19,19,19,19,25,26,26],
                'day':[15,15,15,15,15,17,17,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,57,57,57]})

# initialize the catagory to 1 for counter increament
cat =1

# for the first row the catagory will be 1
new_series = [cat]



# loop will start from 1 and not from 0 because we cannot perform operation on iloc -1
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i]['day'] == df.iloc[i-1]['day']:
        if df.iloc[i]['min'] - df.iloc[i-1]['min'] > 8:
            cat+=1
    else:
        cat+=1
    new_series.append(cat)

df['catagory']= new_series
print(df)
```